# Is it acceptable to put 'music' into a book?

Tags: formatting, world-building, music

I am writing a story about an ancient race of creatures whose culture revolves around music. Each being in the society will have a unique tune or musical motive that represents them (i.e., character X's 'theme; is G-B-F#-A-G-F#-G). I want to have these themes made known to the reader for various reasons.

However, it is quite tedious and inconvenient to have to write it out like I did above. I have access to music-writing software, so I am wondering: **Is it okay to have little snippets of music placed in the text of a book?**

My concern with this is that it will be distracting and inconvenient for readers who cannot read notes. Also, I've never seen this done before, so I am wondering if this would be okay.

(The music would be legible and would be rather sparse in the book. Note: I would not use it as a substitution for the character's name. Also, when present, the single line of music would only take up about four measures.)

Comment: [*Have Spacesuit, Will Travel* by Robert Heinlein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Have_Space_Suit%E2%80%94Will_Travel) does this in a few chapters.  One of the characters is an alien whose speech sounds like bird song.  Several of the passages include notes for the bird song.  At some point, the main character (Kip) decides to stop mentioning the songs.

Comment: If you're very consistent with it, maybe have a constant soundtrack in your footnotes. That's the only way I see it working, in a way that does not break the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plenty of authors use images or short illustrations in their stories to help bring life to them. If this is a story about music and an entire society that revolves around it, then it makes perfect sense to have short snippets of images with musical notes here and there so that any of the more musically inclined audience members can see for themselves what their favorite character's themes are.

*However*

I'd be careful not to go overboard with it. If music is a cornerstone of their society, then these notes symbolize the true nature of the person they represent.

It sounds downright sacred. Sharing this information with a person should be a big deal. It's not just sharing your name with someone, it's essentially laying your entire soul bare to them. Perhaps even more significant (or less, depending on how you want to use it).

If I was writing this I would spare the use of sharing a character's "Theme", for only the most important moments of emotional weight. For example, a character is dramatically dying and decides to share their "true name". Going through with it and showing the actual notes is proof they are legitimately dying.

A sweeter example would be two lovers laying their "Themes" out for one another in a show of ultimate trust. A villain who is turning to the good side may also share his "Theme" with the good guys as a show of good faith.

If the "Theme" has some sort of power attached to it, this may act as an ultimate weapon as well. For example, you know the villain is pulling out all the stops when using it.

This is a very creative concept with lots of uses. Just keep it in your back pocket for only the most high-stakes moments.

Answer (score 5):

Can you do it? Sure. *Should* you do it? I'd have to say I struggle to see it working to any degree of effectiveness.

There's really only going to be a small number of people who will be able to read music well enough to really "hear" the tune you're attempting to present. Even those
that do are going to get an imperfect and limited sense of it - there's a reason why musical notation is not a form anyone effectively "consumes" music in. I *can* read music - but I'd straight up skip over it if it was done this way. Used sparsely  it wouldn't really annoy me or anything, but it definitely wouldn't add anything positive to the experience.

And of course many won't be able to read it even if they wanted to. So anything crucial to the story is going to have to  be relayed so that the non music-literate can still follow.  Which heavily limits it's utility and I'd be concerned that it's pushing into gimmick territory.

While I think the idea of a music-centric culture and of individuals having themes or leitmotifs is actually a pretty cool idea I think if you're wanting to do that you're better off *describing* the sound of the theme and the feelings the characters have when they hear them. You could build effectively "bonus" content for the musically inclined by transcribing the various themes into appendices, or make actual recordings available  e.g. via the internet. That way you can have people get the complete experience *without* putting any obstacles in the way of the average reader.

Comment: I've seen books do this, and not been sure what they were on about. Often by presenting music the author gives the impression that it's a very serious book about music and the author knows their stuff, but whether that impresses the audience or scares them off will depend on other things. Probably best not to do it too soon (wait till the reader is involved), and concentrate it in one place to allow the non-musical reader to skip ahead.